# Does every linear map have this property? $\alpha(0)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Does every linear map $\alpha:A\to B$ have this property?

$$\alpha(0)=0$$

Thanks in advance.

**Reason for question**

I'm doing some homework and the question is:

"Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces and let $v$ be a non-zero vector of $V$ . Is there a linear
transformation  $\Psi:U \to V$ such that the set {$u∈U:\Psi(u)=v$} is a subspace of $U$? Justify your answer. [*End of question*]

Now, if the given set is a subspace of $U$, it must contain the zero vector. Then $v=\Psi(u)=0$. Therefore, if $v$ is non-zero, the set can't be a subspace.

So what this solution is saying, is that if we take the zero vector and apply a linear map, it will equal zero. Is this always the case?

Comment: $\alpha(0u)=0\alpha(u)$

Comment: So the answer is yes?

Comment: Yes. Exercise: Prove $0u=0$ for all $u\in V$ from the axioms of a vector space. The $0$ on the left is the scalar zero, the $0$ on the right is the zero vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

What's
$$\alpha(0+0)?$$

and for the homework, if there's such subspace $S$ so if $u\in S$ then $2u\in S$ so?

Answer (score 2):

Every linear map $\alpha$ satisfies
$$\alpha(\lambda v + \mu w) = \lambda \alpha(v) + \mu \alpha(w)$$
for all scalars $\lambda, \mu$ and vectors $v,w$.

With this in mind, consider $\alpha(v-v)$ for a general vector $v$.